# Cutting in half and rearranging pages of tif document

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-editing, tiff

I scanned in a booklet, and now I have a tif file with "pages" composed of two real pages each, in the order 6/7,5/8,4/9,3/10,2/11,1/12. Is there a way (tool, imagemagick command, etc.) to slice each "page" in half without having to crop each manually twice?

Answer (score 1):

If the pages have to be split in the middle, you can use ImageMagick as follows:

```
-crop 50%x100% +repage
```

The general syntax is `-crop geometry{@}{!}` explained [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop).
Cut out one or more rectangular regions of the image.

You can also use `+repage` (explained [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#repage)) after cropping to remove the page offset that will be left behind.